# How to make several aspect ratio divs to fill remaining screen height?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a calendar-like display which fills the remaining space of the screen height but I can't seem to achieve this.

My expected result looks like this:

```
---------------> top of screen (bottom of browser's address bar -- also start of page)
<!-- some header content -->
<!-- the calendar is here and should be fully shown -->
---------------> bottom of screen
<!-- there're a few extra content here generated through ajax -->
---------------> bottom of page
```

My code is as follows:

```css
.added-top {
  height: 150px;
  background-color: gold;
}

.outer-responsive {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  height: 100%;
}

.outer-responsive .container {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  blackground-color: blue;
}

.row-wrapper {}

.ratio1_1 {
  width: 14%;
  /* 7 days in a week */
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid rgb(235, 235, 235);
  border-right: 0px;
}

.ratio1_1>.content {
  background-color: red;
  width: 99%;
  padding-top: 90%;
  /* 1:1 Aspect Ratio */
  position: relative;
  /* If you want text inside of it */
}

.ratio1_1 .text {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="added-top">
  some previously added content
</div>
<div class="outer-responsive">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row-wrapper">
      <div class="ratio1_1">
        <div class="content">
          <div class="text">Sun</div>
          <!-- If you want text inside the content -->
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="ratio1_1">
        <div class="content">
          <div class="text">Mon</div>
          <!-- If you want text inside the content -->
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="ratio1_1">
        <div class="content">
          <div class="text">Tue</div>
          <!-- If you want text inside the wrapper -->
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="ratio1_1">
        <div class="content">
          <div class="text">Wed</div>
          <!-- If you want text inside the wrapper -->
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="ratio1_1">
        <div class="content">
          <div class="text">Thu</div>
          <!-- If you want text inside the wrapper -->
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="ratio1_1">
        <div class="content">
          <div class="text">Fri</div>
          <!-- If you want text inside the wrapper -->
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="ratio1_1">
        <div class="content">
          <div class="text">Sat</div>
          <!-- If you want text inside the wrapper -->
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row-wrapper">
      <div class="ratio1_1">
        <div class="content">
          <div class="text">Sun</div>
          <!-- If you want text inside the wrapper -->
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="ratio1_1">
        <div class="content">
          <div class="text">Mon</div>
          <!-- If you want text inside the wrapper -->
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="ratio1_1">
        <div class="content">
          <div class="text">Tue</div>
          <!-- If you want text inside the wrapper -->
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="ratio1_1">
        <div class="content">
          <div class="text">Wed</div>
          <!-- If you want text inside the wrapper -->
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="ratio1_1">
        <div class="content">
          <div class="text">Thu</div>
          <!-- If you want text inside the wrapper -->
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="ratio1_1">
        <div class="content">
          <div class="text">Fri</div>
          <!-- If you want text inside the wrapper -->
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="ratio1_1">
        <div class="content">
          <div class="text">Sat</div>
          <!-- If you want text inside the wrapper -->
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row-wrapper">
      <div class="ratio1_1">
        <div class="content">
          <div class="text">Sun</div>
          <!-- If you want text inside the wrapper -->
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="ratio1_1">
        <div class="content">
          <div class="text">Mon</div>
          <!-- If you want text inside the wrapper -->
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="ratio1_1">
        <div class="content">
          <div class="text">Tue</div>
          <!-- If you want text inside the wrapper -->
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="ratio1_1">
        <div class="content">
          <div class="text">Wed</div>
          <!-- If you want text inside the wrapper -->
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="ratio1_1">
        <div class="content">
          <div class="text">Thu</div>
          <!-- If you want text inside the wrapper -->
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="ratio1_1">
        <div class="content">
          <div class="text">Fri</div>
          <!-- If you want text inside the wrapper -->
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="ratio1_1">
        <div class="content">
          <div class="text">Sat</div>
          <!-- If you want text inside the wrapper -->
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row-wrapper">
      <div class="ratio1_1">
        <div class="content">
          <div class="text">Sun</div>
          <!-- If you want text inside the wrapper -->
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="ratio1_1">
        <div class="content">
          <div class="text">Mon</div>
          <!-- If you want text inside the wrapper -->
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="ratio1_1">
        <div class="content">
          <div class="text">Tue</div>
          <!-- If you want text inside the wrapper -->
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="ratio1_1">
        <div class="content">
          <div class="text">Wed</div>
          <!-- If you want text inside the wrapper -->
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="ratio1_1">
        <div class="content">
          <div class="text">Thu</div>
          <!-- If you want text inside the wrapper -->
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="ratio1_1">
        <div class="content">
          <div class="text">Fri</div>
          <!-- If you want text inside the wrapper -->
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="ratio1_1">
        <div class="content">
          <div class="text">Sat</div>
          <!-- If you want text inside the wrapper -->
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's also a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dapidmini/fp70Lze9/) of what my code look so far.. I just can't get the calendar to be responsive according to screen height.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can, you'd be better off using CSS Grid instead of Flexbox to achieve the desired layout, it is more adapted for two dimensional layouts. Here is how you could implement it:

So that the top content and the calendar view takes up the whole height of the screen, you can wrap them in an element and set its height to `100vh`, which is equal to the viewport height.

```css
body {margin: 0;}

.wrapper {
  height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(7, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: auto repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 2px;
}
.header {
  grid-column: 1 / 8;
  grid-row: 1;
  background-color: gold;
}
.day {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="header">
    Some header content<br>
    More content
  </div>
  <div class="day">Sun</div>
  <div class="day">Mon</div>
  <div class="day">Tue</div>
  <div class="day">Wed</div>
  <div class="day">Thu</div>
  <div class="day">Fri</div>
  <div class="day">Sat</div>
  <div class="day">Sun</div>
  <div class="day">Mon</div>
  <div class="day">Tue</div>
  <div class="day">Wed</div>
  <div class="day">Thu</div>
  <div class="day">Fri</div>
  <div class="day">Sat</div>
  <div class="day">Sun</div>
  <div class="day">Mon</div>
  <div class="day">Tue</div>
  <div class="day">Wed</div>
  <div class="day">Thu</div>
  <div class="day">Fri</div>
  <div class="day">Sat</div>
  <div class="day">Sun</div>
  <div class="day">Mon</div>
  <div class="day">Tue</div>
  <div class="day">Wed</div>
  <div class="day">Thu</div>
  <div class="day">Fri</div>
  <div class="day">Sat</div>
</div>
Some extra content
```

I am not quite sure about the content you want to display after the calendar view. Does this satisfy your need?

Comment: yes. it almost completely solve my problem. just one thing though, I see that the .day divs are all automatically square shaped. is there any way to make the .day divs's height stretch to fill the remaining height evenly for every row?

Comment: They actually already do that: the height of every row of the calendar is set to 1fr of a container whose height is 100vh minus the height of the header, that is one fourth of that height. Depending on the height of the viewport, the .day divs will have a different aspect ratio, and only sometime be square shaped.
They can then be wider than taller, as you can see in [this screenshot](https://imgur.com/BXEyfUd).

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to have css grids, you can have something like this:

```css
    .added-top {
    height: 50px;
    background-color: gold;
    }
    .outer-responsive {
    height: calc(100vh - 50px);
    display:block;
    position: relative;
    }

    .row-wrapper {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    height: 25%;
    font-size: 0;
    }
    .ratio1_1 {
    width: 14.2%; /* 7 days in a week */
    height: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid rgb(235, 235, 235);
    border-right: 0px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    .ratio1_1 > .content {
    background-color: red;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative; /* If you want text inside of it */
    }
    .ratio1_1 .text {
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 14px;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link style="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>

    <?php echo put_headers(); ?>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="added-top">
        some previously added content
    </div>
    <div class="outer-responsive">
            <div class="row-wrapper">
                <div class="ratio1_1">
                    <div class="content">
                        <div class="text">Sun</div> <!-- If you want text inside the content -->
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="ratio1_1">
                    <div class="content">
                        <div class="text">Mon</div> <!-- If you want text inside the content -->
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="ratio1_1">
                    <div class="content">
                        <div class="text">Tue</div> <!-- If you want text inside the wrapper -->
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="ratio1_1">
                    <div class="content">
                        <div class="text">Wed</div> <!-- If you want text inside the wrapper -->
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="ratio1_1">
                    <div class="content">
                        <div class="text">Thu</div> <!-- If you want text inside the wrapper -->
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="ratio1_1">
                    <div class="content">
                        <div class="text">Fri</div> <!-- If you want text inside the wrapper -->
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="ratio1_1">
                    <div class="content">
                        <div class="text">Sat</div> <!-- If you want text inside the wrapper -->
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row-wrapper">
                <div class="ratio1_1">
                    <div class="content">
                        <div class="text">Sun</div> <!-- If you want text inside the wrapper -->
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="ratio1_1">
                    <div class="content">
                        <div class="text">Mon</div> <!-- If you want text inside the wrapper -->
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="ratio1_1">
                    <div class="content">
                        <div class="text">Tue</div> <!-- If you want text inside the wrapper -->
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="ratio1_1">
                    <div class="content">
                        <div class="text">Wed</div> <!-- If you want text inside the wrapper -->
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="ratio1_1">
                    <div class="content">
                        <div class="text">Thu</div> <!-- If you want text inside the wrapper -->
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="ratio1_1">
                    <div class="content">
                        <div class="text">Fri</div> <!-- If you want text inside the wrapper -->
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="ratio1_1">
                    <div class="content">
                        <div class="text">Sat</div> <!-- If you want text inside the wrapper -->
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row-wrapper">
                <div class="ratio1_1">
                    <div class="content">
                        <div class="text">Sun</div> <!-- If you want text inside the wrapper -->
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="ratio1_1">
                    <div class="content">
                        <div class="text">Mon</div> <!-- If you want text inside the wrapper -->
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="ratio1_1">
                    <div class="content">
                        <div class="text">Tue</div> <!-- If you want text inside the wrapper -->
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="ratio1_1">
                    <div class="content">
                        <div class="text">Wed</div> <!-- If you want text inside the wrapper -->
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="ratio1_1">
                    <div class="content">
                        <div class="text">Thu</div> <!-- If you want text inside the wrapper -->
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="ratio1_1">
                    <div class="content">
                        <div class="text">Fri</div> <!-- If you want text inside the wrapper -->
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="ratio1_1">
                    <div class="content">
                        <div class="text">Sat</div> <!-- If you want text inside the wrapper -->
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row-wrapper">
                <div class="ratio1_1">
                    <div class="content">
                        <div class="text">Sun</div> <!-- If you want text inside the wrapper -->
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="ratio1_1">
                    <div class="content">
                        <div class="text">Mon</div> <!-- If you want text inside the wrapper -->
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="ratio1_1">
                    <div class="content">
                        <div class="text">Tue</div> <!-- If you want text inside the wrapper -->
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="ratio1_1">
                    <div class="content">
                        <div class="text">Wed</div> <!-- If you want text inside the wrapper -->
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="ratio1_1">
                    <div class="content">
                        <div class="text">Thu</div> <!-- If you want text inside the wrapper -->
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="ratio1_1">
                    <div class="content">
                        <div class="text">Fri</div> <!-- If you want text inside the wrapper -->
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="ratio1_1">
                    <div class="content">
                        <div class="text">Sat</div> <!-- If you want text inside the wrapper -->
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
more contents
</body>
```